# How to implement the confirm dialog from Fancybox 3?

Tags: fancybox-3

I'm a huge fan of Fancybox and I'm using it for years now. At the moment I'm thinking of installing the newest version and I want to use the confirm dialog that is demoed on the project page of Fancybox 3 (https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/). But I don't understand how to do this. Where can I find settings for this, how to initiate the dialog and where does the content that is in the dialog come from?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you display some inline content as usual and then use `afterClose` callback to check what element was clicked to close the modal (tip: add `data-fancybox-close` attribute to any element to act as close button), something like this:

```
afterClose : function( instance, current, e ) {
    var button = e ? e.target || e.currentTarget : null;
    var value  = button ? $(button).data('value') : 0;

    // Here you can choose what to do depending on the element
  }
```

Here is a more complete code - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/YRPoVB?editors=1010 - that is used on the homepage.

Comment: I've found the codepen version of the confirm dialog myself. Content is provided in the javascript file. Problem is that I want it from a database just like other content that I can get with twig.

And to get the script to work, do I have to add the javascript code (from codepen) to the main javascript file of Fancybox? Or use it by adding it in a html file in combination with the main javascript file of Fancybox added as a external script?

Comment: "do I have to add the javascript code (from codepen) to the main javascript file of Fancybox?" - you could do that, but that is not how people usually organize their code. The best practice is to never touch any external file.

Comment: Except for changing config settings? Or is this also done with custom code?

Comment: You place your code wherever you like, but, if it comes before html elements, then simply wrap inside `$( document ).ready()` -  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ Here a simplified demo, hope it helps - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMqqbO?editors=1010